# Remove scss file after using require

Tags: reactjs, sass

I want to use two different react templates (sass) in one app. My idea is to use one template when user is not logged in and another when user is logged. I tried to use *require* for specific path. Problem is once I use *require* I don't know how to remove or delete required file when is no longer needed. Is there such a thing? My idea is something like this.

```
 render() {
        const { user } = this.props;

        if (user) {
            remove("second.scss"); // how to do such a thing??
            require("first.scss");
            return this.authenticatedView();
        }
        else {
            remove("first.scss"); // how to do such a thing??
            require("second.scss");
            return this.anonymousView();
        }
    }
```